# Add 0's to dates where it is missing in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string with a value in the format of

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Now I want to compare that to another string and check if they are equal, the other string can have the value of

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

or sometimes when the day is between 1 and 9:

```
d/mm/yyyy
```

Sometimes when the month is between 1 and 9:

```
dd/m/yyyy
```

So there are a couple of instances where the string isn't equal but the actual date is.
First I only saw that in some cases when the day is between 1-9 it doesn't start with a zero so I did:

```
createdDate = dateField.value.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
createdDate = createdDate.Trim();
if (createdDate.Length == 9)
    createdDate = "0" + createdDate;
```

but then I saw that it can be the same for month so there must be a better way to check this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just parse both, one with the format string "dd/MM/yyyy" and one with the format string "d/M/yyyy" and compare the returned `DateTime` values? After all, the date being represented is the important part, not the *string* representation, presumably.

Comment: ha, too easy... and you answered first, thanks, and thanks everyone else for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

You should use DateTime.Parse to convert both values to dates and then compare the dates.

```
DateTime.Parse("01/01/2001") == DateTime.Parse("1/1/2001")
```

Answer (score 0):

When it are strings, that represent dates, why don't you try to parse them to a date, and compare the date instances that you become ?

you just have to make sure that you use the correct pattern when parsing.

Check out the `DateTime.TryParse` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse both dates into `DateTime`s and then compare them, that way you don't have to worry about different formats in the compare.

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the strings into values of type `DateTime` ([DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)), then use the standard equality comparer (`==`) to compare the dates.